# How map from a stream the sum of a Duration field in java?

Tags: dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to create a map that holds an activity and the total duration of that activity, knowing that the activity appears more times with different durations.

Normally, I would have solved it like this:

```
Map<String,Duration> result2 = new HashMap<String,Duration>();
     for(MonitoredData m: lista)
     {
         if(result2.containsKey(m.getActivity())) result2.replace(m.getActivity(),result2.get(m.getActivity()).plus(m.getDuration()));
         else result2.put(m.getActivity(), m.getDuration());
     }
```

But I am trying to do this with a stream, but I can't figure out how to put the sum in there.

```
Function<Duration, Duration> totalDuration = x -> x.plus(x);
Map<String, Duration> result2 = lista.stream().collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(MonitoredData::getActivity,
                                Collectors.groupingBy(totalDuration.apply(), Collectors.counting()))
                );
```

I tried in various ways to group them, to map them directly, or to sum them directly in the brackets, but i'm stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [3-argument version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) of `toMap` collector:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

Map<String,Duration> result = lista.stream()
    .collect(toMap(MonitoredData::getActivity, MonitoredData::getDuration, Duration::plus));
```

Also, note that `Map` interface got some nice additions in Java 8.  One of them is [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-).  With that, even your iterative for loop can be rewritten to be much cleaner:

```
for (MonitoredData m: lista) {
    result.merge(m.getActivity(), m.getDuration(), Duration::plus);
}
```